# How do I call a method inside ApplicationHelper from my Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, helpermethods

```
# application_helper.rb

def do_some_stuff
   ...
end


# my_model.rb

def my_model_method
   # I want to call the method "do_some_stuff" here, how exactly?
end
```

Obviously, I can't just call `do_some_stuff`, since it would tell me that the model does not have this method.

Comment: y would u need to do so?

Comment: no, you can't. Write method in model and call it on object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding the following line to your model file:

```
include ActionView::Helpers
```

Now, you may want to reconsider placing your helper method somewhere else (e.g. the model, or a mixin module), but use the above line to do what you've asked for.

Comment: You shouldn't give such an answer to this question. Of course it is possible in Ruby/Rails (as most things one can imagine are) but it's a very very very bad thing to do.

Comment: @Michał Szyndel - Do you mean Joe Half Face's comment is the correct answer? Or do you suggest something else?

Comment: @TomDogg of course you can do that. But it's a very bad thing to do. If there's a piece of code that you need in you model - it should be in model. Then you may call in in controller and in view (on instance or class)